# C# Multi-threading, wait for all task to complete in a situation when new tasks are being constantly added

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a situation where new tasks are being constantly generated and added to a `ConcurrentBag<Tasks>`.

I need to wait all tasks to complete.

Waiting for all the tasks in the `ConcurrentBag` via `WaitAll` is not enough as the number of tasks would have grown while the previous wait is completed.

At the moment I am waiting it in the following way:

```
private void WaitAllTasks()
{
    while (true)
    {
        int countAtStart = _tasks.Count();
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());

        int countAtEnd = _tasks.Count();
        if (countAtStart == countAtEnd)
        {
            break;
        }

        #if DEBUG
        if (_tasks.Count() > 100)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            break;
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

I am not very happy with the `while(true)` solution.

Can anyone suggest a better more efficient way to do this (without having to pool the processor constantly with a `while(true)`)

---

Additional context information as requested in the comments. I don't think though this is relevant to the question.

This piece of code is used in a web crawler. The crawler scans page content and looks for two type of information. Data Pages and Link Pages. Data pages will be scanned and data will be collected, Link Pages will be scanned and more links will be collected from them.

As each of the tasks carry-on the activities and find more links, they add the links to an `EventList`. There is an event `OnAdd` on the list (code below) that is used to trigger other task to scan the newly added URLs. And so forth.

The job is complete when there are no more running tasks (so no more links will be added) and all items have been processed.

```
public IEventList<ISearchStatus> CurrentLinks { get; private set; }
public IEventList<IDataStatus> CurrentData { get; private set; }
public IEventList<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> ResultData { get; set; }
private readonly ConcurrentBag<Task> _tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

private readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private readonly CancellationToken token;

public void Search(ISearchDefinition search)
{
    CurrentLinks.OnAdd += UrlAdded;
    CurrentData.OnAdd += DataUrlAdded;

    var status = new SearchStatus(search);

    CurrentLinks.Add(status);

    WaitAllTasks();

    _exporter.Export(ResultData as IList<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>);
}

private void DataUrlAdded(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = o as IDataStatus;
    if (item == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessObjectSearch(item), token));
}

private void UrlAdded(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = o as ISearchStatus;
    if (item==null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessFollow(item), token));
    _tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessData(item), token));
}

 public class EventList<T> : List<T>, IEventList<T>
{
    public EventHandler OnAdd { get; set; }
    private readonly object locker = new object();
    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        //lock (locker)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
        OnAdd?.Invoke(item, null);
    }

    public new bool Contains(T item)
    {
        //lock (locker) 
        {
            return base.Contains(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, and this may not be the best solution to your problem here, but you should take a look at TPL Dataflow. It allows you to create asynchronous pipelines.

Comment: Why are new tasks generated constantly? Why do you add them to a `ConcurrentBag`? Why do you need to wait for all tasks to complete?

Comment: If you want to wait for all tasks to be finished then why is your condition `countAtStart == countAtEnd` and not `countAtEnd == 0`?

Comment: @john Yes my problem can be implemented using TPL Data-flows, thank you for pointing that out. I will look into, though it feels a bit of of an overkill. The amount of code to write seems massive.

Comment: @PJvG Running Tasks generate more running tasks. At any point in time when i use the ConcurrentBag items to do a Task.WaitAll, by the moment all items have been waited, the number of items (task) has grown so the WaitAll will not have waited them all. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Servy if by the time i was waiting for all tasks to complete, more tasks were added to the _tasks bag, then it means i haven't waited them all, hence the while(true) loop to wait again. Only when all were waited and nothing was added i would have waited all tasks. This solutions works fine. I don't like the pooling implementation.

Comment: @YlliPrifti, The documentation for TPL Dataflow is very daunting but you don't actually need most of it to achieve what you appear to want. I little investment now will pay dividends in maintenance. IMHO This type of code is fraught with complex edge cases so why not reuse and avoid?

Comment: What's your task doing? What is the input for it?

Comment: Hope the down-voter will care to give a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this task can be done with `TPL Dataflow` library with very basic setup. You'll need a `TransformManyBlock<Task, IEnumerable<DataTask>>` and an `ActionBlock` (may be more of them) for actual data processing, like this:

```
// queue for a new urls to parse
var buffer = new BufferBlock<ParseTask>();

// parser itself, returns many data tasks from one url
// similar to LINQ.SelectMany method
var transform = new TransformManyBlock<ParseTask, DataTask>(task =>
{
    // get all the additional urls to parse
    var parsedLinks = GetLinkTasks(task);
    // get all the data to parse
    var parsedData = GetDataTasks(task);

    // setup additional links to be parsed
    foreach (var parsedLink in parsedLinks)
    {
        buffer.Post(parsedLink);
    }

    // return all the data to be processed
    return parsedData;
});

// actual data processing
var consumer = new ActionBlock<DataTask>(s => ProcessData(s));
```

After that you need to link the blocks between each over:

```
buffer.LinkTo(transform, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
transform.LinkTo(consumer, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Now you have a nice pipeline which will execute in background. At the moment you realize that everything you need is parsed, you simply call the [`Complete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete.aspx) method for a block so it stops accepting news messages. After the `buffer` became empty, it will propagate the completion down the pipeline to `transform` block, which will propagate it down to consumer(s), and you need to wait for [`Completion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.completion.aspx) task:

```
// no additional links would be accepted
buffer.Complete();
// after all the tasks are done, this will get fired
await consumer.Completion;
```

You can check the moment for a completion, for example, if both `buffer`' [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194818.aspx) property **and** `transform`' [`InputCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160350.aspx) **and** `transform`' `CurrentDegreeOfParallelism` (this is internal property for the `TransformManyBlock`) are equal to `0`.

However, I suggested you to implement some additional logic here to determine current transformers number, as using the internal logic isn't a great solution. As for cancelling the pipeline, you can create a `TPL` block with a `CancellationToken`, either the one for all, or a dedicated for each block, getting the cancellation out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write one function that yields your tasks as necessary, when they are created? This way you can just use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait for them to complete or, have I missed the point? [See this working here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3h1xTn).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Task.WhenAll(GetLazilyGeneratedSequenceOfTasks()).Wait();   
            Console.WriteLine("Fisnished.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);  
        }   
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Task> GetLazilyGeneratedSequenceOfTasks()
    {
        var random =  new Random();
        var finished = false;
        while (!finished)
        {
            var n = random.Next(1, 2001);
            if (n < 50)
            {
                finished = true;
            }

            if (n > 499)
            {
                yield return Task.Delay(n);
            }

            Task.Delay(20).Wait();              
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if your question is not as trivial as my answer may suggest, I'd consider a mesh with [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). The combination of a [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx) and an [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) would get you very close to what you need. You could [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Either way, I'd suggest you want to include a provision for accepting a `CancellationToken` or two.

Comment: I think that the code you've provided won't work, as some additional tasks may be added, and enumeration will throw.

Comment: @VMAtm my idea is, don't `yield break` until want the sequence to be complete. However, as I state, for any non-trivial solution investigate TPL Dataflow.

Comment: This doesn't work as the list of tasks is modified as the yield is happening.

Comment: @YlliPrifti, you can keep tacking them on if you haven't done a `yield break` yet. Just don't call `yield break` until you know you've finished.

Comment: I tired  you answer and it doesn't work. I was expecting it not to work. In fact the evaluation of the GetLazilyDefinedSequenceOfTasks completed before the wait. The wait thought would have generated new items that will not be considered.

Comment: This is how it looks like:   

`code`
 IEnumerable<Task> GetLazilyDefinedSequenceOfTasks()
        {
            yield return _tasks.First(c=>c.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
           
        }

        private void WaitAllTasks() {
            Task.WaitAll(GetLazilyDefinedSequenceOfTasks().ToArray());
}
`code`

Comment: @YlliPrifti, use `Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`, like in my answer. Then you don't need to `ToArray` the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Jodrell that was my first try. No luck

Comment: @YlliPrifti, I've posted a completed example. Does this make sense?

Comment: I will try this later. However my problem can be expressed like this: Initially cycle a list of items. Additionally each task might add more items to the list. That creates the asynchronous situation where you don't know if you can continue until the last task has been waited and no more items were added. This check needs to be atomic. If you are returning the last item but still have to wait for it, more items might be added.